# How ton run an eclipse java applet in a web browser via a network

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, applet

I've got two files in my eclipse project:
the .html file contains an object tag with information for a java applet,
and the .java file contains the java applet.

I manage to run the applet in a java window easily; but I'd like to run the java applet inside an external browser, and I'd like to load it via a network. ("Open with... browser" just opens the html file locally, and the applet doesn't work.)

Isn't there a way to do this directly from within eclipse? Or do I need to create a jar file?

Answer (score 2):

**NO**,

You must firstly create Web Server project in Eclipse (be sure that you installed some Tomcat)

or use other one, after, put your Applet as jar file  into Web Server under `WebContent/web`

Comment: Thank you. Hm, eclipse only allows me to create Dynamic Web Project, Static Web Project and Web Fragment Project. I cannot find a Web Server Project.

Comment: Set `Dynamic Web Project`